# How can I expose a constant defined in unmanaged code to managed code?

Tags: c#, .net, macros, interop, unmanaged

I have a C++ DLL which has a constant defined as such:

```cpp
#define GPC_EPSILON (DBL_EPSILON)
```

Is there any way to expose this `GPC_EPSILON` to the managed DLL via interop so that I can get this value from the .NET DLL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Constants in `#define`'s are replaced by the pre-processor before compilation. They are not exposed as variables.